# Rename all file in a Folder

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to rename all the file in a folder using this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for "%file_path_history%" %%a in (*.*) do (
if not "%~nx0"=="%%a" ren "%%a" "%fullstamp%_%%a"
)
```

But it returns an error message:

> path was unexpected at this time.

I have also tried

```
ren "%file_path_history%*.*" "%file_path_history%%fullstamp%_*.*"
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where are set `file_path_history` and `fullstamp`?

Comment: Above; doing the rename on a single file it works correctly, so I assume the problem is not related with those varibale, maybe on their calls/usage...

Comment: May you forgot the /r switch in the for /r......

Comment: May you give an example of how the files are currently and how you want them to be?

Comment: sure: current name is "abc.xlsx", "def.csv" and I want to have "20221025_141500_abc.xlsx", "20221025_141500_def.csv", for all the file in the %file_path_history% folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd %file_path_history%
for %%a in (*.*) do (
ren "%%a" "%fullstamp%_%%a"
)
```

Thanks,
Andrea